# How can I see which files are preventing a duplication in OS X?

Tags: macos, file-transfer, file-permissions

I'm trying to make a simple backup of an external disk onto my macbook using the `Duplicate` function:

[image: duplicating mattp]

It's a few hundred GB so it takes a while, but fails close to the end without a lot of detail:

[image: failed because of permissions]

**Where can I look to get more detail about which files/directories are actually preventing the duplcation from finishing?**

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate is not the best method for moving hundreds of gigabytes of data.  The idea behind duplicate is that you would use it when you want to make another copy of something *in the same place*.  An external drive is kind of like a place of it's own, with files inside of it.  A physical disk has a partition map which is going to point to one or more volumes which are the orange things showing up on your picture.  Copying one of those things is not really what you mean, and certainly not duplicate.  If you mean to copy what's inside, go ahead and try drag and drop on the whole volume or open it up and drag what's inside.

You might want to look into using the `rsync` command from a terminal if it still turns out that Finder chokes during the transfer.